# Android Bluetooth transfer

Tags: android, bluetooth

If 2 phones say "A" and "B" are Bluetooth paired. Can "A" directly pull contacts from "B" (without "B" pushing contacts to "A")?

After the devices "A" and "B" are Bluetooth paired. "A" should be able to pull the contacts/images from "B" without any restrictions.

Comment: If B supports Bluetooth Phone Book Access (PBAP) Server, then PBAP Client on A can request for contacts from B.

Answer (score 1):

Normally for Android phone the PBAP client aka PCE does not implemented but all implement PBAP server.
Android source do have PBAP client code, you may compile it and add vcard store action then you can pull contacts from B.
Paired only means that the transportation will be encrypted and both device see each device as trusted, does not mean you can do anything.